# React Native AsyncStorage not overwriting data

Tags: arrays, react-native, object, mobile, asyncstorage

I am trying to make an app and I have a few objects in an array which I use AsyncStorage for. I need to change one element of an object but if I try changing it, it doesn't keep those changes.

My code:

```
save = async () => {
this.state.dataSource.notes = this.state.text;
try {
  AsyncStorage.clear();
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('medicines', JSON.stringify(this.state.dataSource));
} catch (error) {
  console.log('error');
}
this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
```

The `this.state.text` stores the value of the text input.

The `this.state.dataSource` stores the array of objects.

Both of these work like they should.

The array looks like this:

```
Array = [
item = {
    id: 'id',
    name: 'name',
    brand: 'brand',
    inname: 'inname',
    chosenWeekDay: 'week day',
    androidDate: 'date for android',
    chosenAndroidTime: 'time for android',
    notes: 'notes in a string',
  }]
```

Comment: How are you selecting the specific item in AsyncStorage you want to change? For example, are you using the `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solutions:

```
save = async () => {
  this.changeNotes(this.state.id, this.state.text);
  try {
    AsyncStorage.clear();
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('medicines', JSON.stringify(this.state.dataSource));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error');
  }
  this.setModalVisible(!this.state.modalVisible);
}


 changeNotes( value, note ) {
  for (var i in this.state.dataSource) {
    if (this.state.dataSource[i].id == value) {
      this.state.dataSource[i].notes = note;
      break;
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target a specific object in your `dataSource` array

```
let { dataSource, text } = this.state;
const yourSpecfiicIndex = 12; // whatever
dataSource[yourSpecfiicIndex].notes = text;

//...

await AsyncStorage.setItem('medicines', JSON.stringify(dataSource));
```

Comment: if I console.log clonedDataSource it gives me `Object {
   "0": Object {
     "brand": "Ziagen",
     "chosenDate": "2019-03-22T08:36:24.024Z",
     "chosenWeekDay": "Ma",
     "id": 104,
     "inname": "day",
     "name": "Abacavir",
     "notes": "Type je notities hier....",
   },
   "notes": "Test",
}`

Comment: It has been parsed like this:
`const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('medicines');
      if(value !== null) {
        const allMeds = JSON.parse(value);
        this.setState({
          dataSource: allMeds
        });
      }`

Comment: I'm sorry ... I was wrong ... your datasource is actually an array not an object, you need to access a specific index ... revise the answer plz